# Why the info of the registration types associated with the registration are appearing incorrectly?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `PaymentController` where I return to the view the `registrationTypeDetails`, the `total` and `type_counts`. So is possible to show a summary of the registration like below. In this case the user did a registration with two participants in the registration type "general" so it should appear a summary like:

```
+-------------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| Registration Type | Quantity |  Price  |   Subtotal   |      
+-------------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| general           | 2        | 10.00 € |      20.00 € |
+-------------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| TOTAL             |          |         |      20.00 € |
+-------------------+----------+---------+--------------+
```

But it's appearing like below, with repeated info:

```
+-------------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| Registration Type | Quantity |  Price  |   Subtotal   |      
+-------------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| general           | 2        | 10.00 € |      20.00 € |
| general           | 2        | 10.00 € |      20.00 € |
+-------------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| TOTAL             |          |         |      20.00 € |
+-------------------+----------+---------+--------------+
```

Do you know why the info of the registration types associated with the registration are appearing twice?

In the payment.blade.php view to show the summary of the registration:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>Registration Type</span>
            <span>Quantity</span>
            <span>Price</span>
            <span>Subtotal</span>
        </li>

        @foreach( $registrationTypeDetails->participants as $participant )
            <li>
                <span>{{$participant->registration_type->name}}</span>
                <span>{{$type_counts[$name]}}</span>
                <span>{{ number_format($participant->registration_type->price, 2)}}$</span>
                <span>{{ number_format($participant->registration_type->price * $type_counts[$name], 2)}}$</span>
            </li>
        @endforeach

        <li>
            <span>TOTAL</span>
            <span>{{ number_format($total, 2)}}$</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

Complete code of the `PaymentController` `payment()` method where I get the registration types info associated with the registration and redirect the user to the payment page with this info to show a summary of the registration in the payment page.

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{

// method that shows the payment page
public function payment($id, $slug, $regID)
{
    $regPaid = Registration::where('id', $regID)->pluck('status')->first();

    // if the registration is incomplete because the user didnt pay yet 
    if ($regPaid == "I") {

        // get the current user
        $user_id = Auth::id();

        $conferenceDetails = Registration::with([
            'conference' => function ($query) {
                $query->select('id', 'name', 'start_date');
            }
        ])->find($regID);

        $registrationTypeDetails = Registration::with(['participants.registration_type',
            'participants' => function ($query) use ($regID) {
                $query->select('id', 'registration_type_id', 'registration_id')->where('registration_id', $regID);
            }
        ])->find($regID);

        $price = $registrationTypeDetails->participants->sum(function ($participant) {
            return $participant->registration_type->price;
        });

        $total = $price;
        $totalStripe = $total * 100;

        if ($registrationTypeDetails->main_participant_id != $user_id) {
            return redirect('/');
        } else {
            $type_counts = [];
            foreach ($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p) {
                $name = $p->registration_type->name;
                if (!isset($type_counts[$name])) {
                    $type_counts[$name] = 0;
                }
                $type_counts[$name]++;
            }

            Session::put('total', $total);
            Session::put('totalStripe', $totalStripe);
            Session::put('registrationID', $regID);

            $conferenceDetails = [
                'name' => $conferenceDetails->conference->name,
                'start_date' => $conferenceDetails->conference->start_date
            ];

            Session::put('conference_name', $conferenceDetails['name']);
            Session::put('date', $conferenceDetails['end_date']);

            return view('conferences.payment', compact('conferenceDetails', 'name', 'total', 'type_counts', 'registrationTypeDetails', 'id', 'slug'));
        }
    } else {

        Session::flash('registration_complete', 'Your registration is already paid.');
        return redirect(route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()]) . '#myTickets');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problems is coming from the way you construct your data. 
Use left join and methods from Model would strongly make your code more readable and helps you to debug. I don't know whether it's good or not to use with() like how you did.

Some of the functions really need to go into your model's file to make it OOP.

The way of gathering data into that conferenceDetails is a whole bunch of mess to me. I would suggest you to not only think about gathering all data you need, but also think about how the data is structured.

In your case, Conference, Registration, Participant are 3 major model. Your code messed up the relationships between each other. If your program is focused on Conference, then use Conference as the major model and get data base on it. Like:

```
$registrations=$conference->registrations;
$participants=$conference->participants;
```

Not using $conference->participants() is because the participants() should return a relation not a collection whereas participants returns the collection you will need. This is done by Laravel

Now you can see, conference data is conference data, do not mess it up with participants and registrations.
In your Conference model, write a function called particiants(), and in there do the work of getting data through a many to many relationship. You can find example code in Laravel docs.

In addition, I wouldn't suggest you to touch on payments if your are a starter. A payment system requires much more than what I can see from you code. The transactions, the refunds and a lot more. Even if you are using Stripe, I can still see you don't have a solid understanding of MVC programming. If I was writing this program, I would get many steps done over Ajax and provide a more user friendly interactive interface with more detailed errors and messages to help the users.

Anyway, check the code below and adjust it to fit your needs. Do not use your program on a production program, it definitely will cause nightmares. Especially when payments are related.

```
public function payment($id, $slug, $regID){
$reg=Registration::find($regID); //It's always good to check if the instance exists
if(!$reg){
    return back()->with(['error'=>'Could not find the Registration with the given ID']);
}

if($reg->status=='I'){ //By the way, if the status is an integer, it would be better for database design in MySQL
    $isRegPaid=false;
} else {
    $isRegPaid=true;
}

// get the current user
$user_id = Auth::id(); //remember you can also use $request->user() if the function provides Request $request as a parameter

// if the registration is incomplete because the user didnt pay yet 
if ($isRegPaid) {
    $conferenceDetails = Registration::with([
        'conference' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'name', 'start_date');
        }
    ])->find($regID);

    $conferences=Conference::where('registration_id',$regID)->get();
    //        $registrationTypeDetails = Registration::with(['participants.registration_type',
    //            'participants' => function ($query) use ($regID) {
    //                $query->select('id', 'registration_type_id', 'registration_id')->where('registration_id', $regID);
    //            }
    //        ])->find($regID);

    $total=0;
    //As I don't know the actual structure of your model, I could only provide you the most basic way to sum the price
    //If I was writing my own code, I could do a lot more than this like left join etc.
    //And you also need to remember to put some of the functions into your Model, to make it more Object Oriented
    foreach($conferences as $conference){
        //I'm assuming participants is actually a function is Conference, if it's in Registration, you will need to rewrite this part
        foreach($conference->participants as $participant){
            $total+=$participant->registration_type->price;
        }
    }

    $totalStripe = $total * 100;

    if($reg->main_participant_id != $user_id){ //I'm guessing this main_participant_id property belongs to Registration
        return back()->with(['error'=>'You do not have the permission to process this payment']); //Let the user know what error they have encountered, it's good for debugging
    } else {
        $type_counts = [];
        foreach($conferences as $conference){
            foreach($conference->participants as $participant){
                $name = $participant->registration_type->name; // I don't know how you could get this name property, assuming registration_type should be a function
                if (!isset($type_counts[$name])) {
                    $type_counts[$name] = 0;
                }
                $type_counts[$name]++;
            }
        }

        Session::put('total', $total);
        Session::put('totalStripe', $totalStripe);
        Session::put('registrationID', $regID);

        //You will need to rewrite this part to format your data
        //            $conferenceDetails = [
        //                'name' => $conferenceDetails->conference->name,
        //                'start_date' => $conferenceDetails->conference->start_date
        //            ];

        Session::put('conference_name', $conferenceDetails['name']);
        Session::put('date', $conferenceDetails['end_date']);

        //            return view('conferences.payment', compact('conferences', 'name', 'total', 'type_counts', 'registrationTypeDetails', 'id', 'slug'));
        //ID should not need to be rendered into the view as it should be able to be accessed from Request
        //I don't like using compact, I usually do this:
        return view('conferences.payment')->with(['conferences'=>$conferences,'name'=>$name,'total'=>$total,'type_counts'=>$type_counts,
            'slug'=>$slug]);
    }
} else {
    Session::flash('registration_complete', 'Your registration is already paid.');
    return redirect(route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()]) . '#myTickets');
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but like that it appears "Trying to get property of non-object
" in "if($reg->status=='I'){ 
            $isRegPaid=false;
        } else {
            $isRegPaid=true;
        }".

Comment: You will see this error very often in the future, it means the $reg is not a valid object that can be accessed with ->xxxxxx , because only objects have attributes. After $reg=Registration::find($regID);, use dd($reg) to see what $reg is. Because I have already checked if(!$reg), it shouldn't have the chance to give you such error

Comment: $reg shows "I". So it should be if($reg == "I") instead of "$reg->status". But like that is not working properly when the user clicks in the link "Pay" it appears always "Your registration is already paid.", but it was not paid.

Comment: Maybe the issue is in the part where the info is show with "@foreach( $registrationTypeDetails->participants as $participant )
            <li>
             <span>{{$name}}</span>
                <span>{{$type_counts[$name]}}</span>
                <span>{{ number_format($participant->registration_type->price, 2)}}$</span>
                <span>{{ number_format($participant->registration_type->price * $type_counts[$name], 2)}}$</span></li> @endforeach". Because "                                    @foreach($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $participant)
" shows two participants.

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't adopted all of my code. If you are stil using your old code, it's a different scenario. If my code solves your problem then it is the solution. I won't be able to give you any advices if you stick with your old code.  The $reg in the code I provided, is an object instance, not a string. The $registrationTypeDetails should be removed straight away as I have mentioned, this is messing up the data.

Comment: Thanks, but like that appears " Your registration is already paid.
" when the "Pay"  button is clicked, but the registration was not paid yet. So like that is no possible to check if the registration types associated with the registration are appearing twice because is not possible to go to the payment page since it says " Your registration is already paid.
" .

Comment: It only shows the message "Your reg is already paid" when $isRegPaid=true; Check the records in your database or use dd($isRegPaid) to see what is going on with this variable.

Comment: $isRegPaid shows false but the message that appears when the pay button is clicked is " Your registration is already paid.
".

Comment: Please accept the answer if it answers your question.